# Get max value from a joined list paired with another column in DB2

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, subquery, max

I have the following tables:

Table I:

```
 etu |  nr |
  1     2
  2     2
  2     3
  2     1
  3     4
  3     9
```

Table A:

```
 etu | rsp | nr
  2     8    2
  2     7    3
  2     3    1
  3     2    4
  3     6    9
```

Now what I want to have as a result table is

```
 etu  |  nr | rsp 
  2..    3     7
  3..    9     6
```

So etu and nr are linked together and if multiple equal etu entries are available only the one with the highest nr is taken and the rsp value is added in the result table. in addition if more etu entries are available in the table I there are .. added to the etu value.

Explain: For the 3 9 6 row: The last row on table I is 3 9 so 3 is the number that is looked for and 9 is the highest number for the 3 rows. So we take that and add the rsp value for that ( 6 ) and we add that to the result table. For the 2 row it is the same 2 3 being the highest 2 row in table I.

I got something like:

```
 select x.etu, x.rsp, y.nr from(
 select i.etu etu, max(i.nr) maxnr, a.rsp from i left join a on
 i.etu=a.etu and i.nr=a.nr group by etu)t
 inner join a x on x.etu=t.etu and x.nr=t.nr inner join y on y.etu=t.etu 
 and y.nr=t.nr
```

or

```
 select i.etu, max(i.nr) a.rsp from i left join a on i.etu=a.etu and 
 i.nr=a.nr grounp by
```

None even get me close to get the results that I want less add the .. after the etu when having the right result.

The system is DB10.5 Windows.

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Viking

Comment: You need to work on the description.  What do the two tables have to do with the problem?  The logic for the output makes no sense.  How does "9" appear in the `nr` column, when the data has no row with "9" in `nr`?

Comment: Did you intend to swap the `rsp` and `nr` values, or is that a typo?

Comment: typo i correct that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE here like this:

```
with tmp as (
  select i.etu, max(i.nr) as nt, count(*) as cnt
    from i
    group by i.etu)
select case
         when tmp.cnt = 1 then char(a.etu)
         else concat(rtrim(char(a.etu)), '..')
       end as etu,
       a.nr, 
       a.rsp
  from tmp
    left outer join a 
      on a.etu = tmp.etu
        and a.nr = tmp.nr
```

The CTE provides the information necessary to join with `a` to get the correct response, and append the `..` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks it works. I needed to change the tmp select because not all etu are in both tables but i works great now.

Comment: do a right join, or swap the order of `tmp` and `a`